# PromtQL function "count by (argument1, argument2)"

Tags: prometheus

I write some requests in Prometheus (PromQL) and just want to understand, how function "count by (argument1, argument2)" works? 
If we have one argument - it's easy, but I couldn't find info about count by for many arguments.

Could anybody explain please?

Answer (score 0):

The [aggregation operators](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#aggregation-operators) in PromQL are accumulating the values of metrics along a dimension. In prometheus, dimensions are represented by label names and values; all metrics with the [same value on the same label](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/data_model/#metric-names-and-labels) have a common dimension.

If you don't preserve dimensions, the aggregation will by carried out on all values, discarding any label.

By example, given the following metrics (the content of my fridge):

```
fruit_number{name="apple",color="red",size="small"}             2
fruit_number{name="apple",color="green",size="big"}             1
fruit_number{name="banana",color="green",size="small"}          1
vegetable_number{name="salad",color="green",size="big"}         1
vegetable_number{name="mushroom",color="red",size="small"}      3
```

The sum of all fruits and vegetables `sum(fruit_number OR vegetable_number)` will product a single scalar:

```
{}     8
```

But if you want apply the operator only on some dimensions you can use the `by` clause to indicate which label(s) should be preserved.

Retaking the same metrics, if I want to known the number of perishable food by `color` and by `size`, I will request `sum(fruit_number OR vegetable_number) by (color,size)`:

```
{color="red",size="small"}      5
{color="green",size="big"}      2
{color="green",size="small"}    1
```

It aggregates the values for which the label set is the same and apply the operator (`sum` in this case):

- `{color="red",size="small"}   -> red apple + mushroom`
- `{color="green",size="big"}   -> green apple + salad`
- `{color="green",size="small"} -> banana`